# C++ - Read in file lines separated by a comma

Tags: c++, csv, ifstream, getline

I tried looking up what I'm trying to do but I cant find specifically what I'm trying to do. I have a text file with multiple lines that look like this:

```
12345,12345,12.34,12345,12345
```

It's the same format on every line and I want to get each line and plug the numbers into certain variables. Something like this:

```
file >> int1 >> int2 >> double1 >> int3 >> int4;
```

But this is very hard for me to do because of the comma separating each number. I used to be able to do this when there was a 'space' but the comma is really throwing me off. Any ideas?

Comment: Read the file into an `int`, and then into a `char`.

Comment: I apologize, I saw that one but I thought it was different because I saw spaces after the comma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char ch;
file >> int1 >> ch >> int2 >> ch >> dbl >> ch >> int3 >> ch >> int4;
```

Comment: @gongzhitaao: which could be any character... This is non-robust.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit True. But the OP has the assumption that *It's the same format on every line*

Comment: @gongzhitaao: ... and relying on that assumption holding for all inputs is non-robust.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/).

Something like this?

```
 fscanf(filepointer, "%d,%d,%f,%d,%d\n", &int1, &int2, &double1, &int3, &int4);
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. So wait, I'm new to this but since I'm using C++, then everything in C should work as well?

Comment: @Arubix: Yes. It's a matter of debate as to whether you _should_ use any C library functions, though. At the very least, minimise your use of them. But for I/O often they're better.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  Or worse.  For example, scanf should *never* (and by never I mean almost never) be used with %s.

Answer (score 0):

The earlier suggestions work well.  However, if you can use c++11 and need a more robust solution, I would suggest the c++11 regex library: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex